# Android O: Notification Channel name localization

Tags: android, localization, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

I'm facing similar problem mentioned here in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317545/android-o-notification-channel-localization).  Have notification channel got created something like this,

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOOBAR, getContext().getString(R.string.notification_channel_foobar), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

The string used as channel name `R.string.notification_channel_foobar` is not getting reflected with appropriate locale string when keyboard language gets changed. The suggested solution is to listen for `ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED` and update the channel name again by invoking `createNotificationChannel` api.

Consider the following scenario,

1. Device keyboard language is English now
2. Changed the language to Japanese
3. Rebooted the device

I'm expecting the appropriate Japanese string to get updated for the notification channel name. But this is not happening. Am I missing something? Or how this could have happened?

Comment: keyboard lang != device lang. but still you are right, you are passing fixed `String` fetched at the moment of channel creation, so further device lang change won't change this name...

Comment: Why would you want to to do that  ?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim : Trying to understand, here after reboot the notification channel would be created for the first time. So here in this case it should have fetched the appropriate (from Japanese folder instead of english) value right?